# How to use Web Scraping After login using MVC .net, If API to login is not available

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-scraping

I have to achieve Web Scraping using MVC .net, But firstly i have to login to second site to fetch data (Like login to Admin) where API to login is not available.

For example i have to Scrape data from `https://talent.stackoverflow.com/users/login`
but after login i want to fetch data from user page. Is it possible to Scrape data from this url after login through MVC .Net, if i have credentials.

Answer (score 4):

If you are going to make a crawler than you need to go ahead with any client side scripting.

I suggest you, If you have any idea of data crawling than go ahead with **PhantomJs** or **CasperJs** because its provide many functions especially for scraping.

As an example, CasperJs identify the process execution one by one.
Lets say You are login into any website and you need to wait for response than CasperJs provide **"then"** function to determine for response.

Lets take another example, If you hits many request and web site might be gives captcha screen to enter captcha code in this circumstances you can take screenshot of that and handle captcha at runtime.

Comment: thanks for replay, But i want to know is it not possible to login another site using my mvc C# application if i have login credentials?

Comment: Hi Amandeep, Might be below link will useful to you.

http://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/customizing-external-login-buttons-in-asp-net-mvc-4/